# ExtJS4 - MVC Store, retrieve data

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a controller with store, model and view (toolbar) :

```
Ext.define('Cc.controller.Headers', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

  stores: ['User'],
  models: ['Agent'],
  views: ['Header'],


  refs: [
    { ref: 'navigation', selector: 'navigation' },
    { ref: 'tabPanel', selector: 'tabpanel' },
    { ref: 'head', selector: 'head' },
    { ref: 'logoutButton', selector: 'head button[action=logout]'},
    { ref: 'helpButton', selector: 'head button[action=help]'}
  ],

  init: function() {
    this.control({
      'head button[action=logout]': {
        beforerender: this.initLogoutButton,
        click: this.onClickLogoutButton
      },
      'head button[action=help]':{
        click: this.onClickHelpButton
      }
    });
  },

  initLogoutButton: function(a){
    var store = this.getUserStore(),
      button = this.getLogoutButton();
    store.load();
    var user = this.getAgentModel();
    button.setText('Logout ['+user.get('lastname')+']');
    console.log(store.count());
  },

  onClickLogoutButton: function(view, record, item, index, e){
    alert('déconnexion');
  },

  onClickHelpButton: function(view, record, item, index, e){
    alert('help');
  }
});
```

my problem is in the **initLogoutButton** function. I need to retrieve the only instance of user I get from ajax request (always only one instance). I can see the request in js console, all is good, but I can't set variable or array with this data !

In addition, the *store.count()* function return **0**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a proxy to load data into your store, you should note that the request asynchronous! you need to set the button text after the store is loaded with data.

```
store.load({
    scope   : this,
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        // check for success and set the value of button        
    }
});
```

The callback function is called after the store is loaded and then you set the button value.

Comment: okay and thank you, sorry for my ignorance, but in the API docs, I don't see the class of records object. How parse it ?

Comment: docs doesn't explain it. Also the function that you see in docs comes from 3.x so, I suggest you inspect the object using firebug or other developer tools. I think you should get object of type `Ext.data.Model`

Comment: I don't understand anything... As you say and as I saw, I should get object of type Ext.data.Model, exactly Cc.model.Agent, my own class which inherits from Ext.data.Model. Ok, but I check few methods from this class and error, error, error :

_records.getId is not a function_

Comment: that is exactly why I asked you to check the firebug.. put a breakpoint and CHECK the object.. you need to learn this as its one of the basic debugging method in javascript and ExtJS

Comment: Yes, I know that, I use firebug. I have the solution, but I can't explain it :

    `initLogoutButton: function(a){
      var store = this.getUserStore(),
        button = this.getLogoutButton();
      store.load({
        scope   : this,
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {
          if(success){
            button.setText('Logout ['+store.first().get('firstname')+' '+store.first().get('lastname')+']');
          }
        }
      });
    },`

why **store** and not **records** ???

Comment: Ok, I understand records is a collection so an other way to do that :

`button.setText('Logout ['+records[0].get('firstname')+' '+records[0].get('lastname')+']');`

Comment: there is no records in extjs 4. its replaced with Model. But remember most of the methods return a store a not just a model object.

Comment: ok thank you. So if I wan't to call the callback function from another controller, can I ?

Comment: callback function is an ordinary method. only thing is its automatically called after some process. You should be able to call a function in another controller. It actually depends how you code. In the above example, you can't call because its an anonymous function.